# Problems with inputting text into Discord Message Box using Selenium Python

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a program that logins to Discord, goes to a selected channel, and implicitly waits for a text channel to show up. Once the text channel with the required name pops up, it clicks onto the channel, writes $claim, and presses enter.

However,  I'm having trouble with the writing part. Selenium's send_keys command is not working and I'm not sure if it's problem with my syntax or problems with locating the message box.

Once Selenium clicks the channel, the cursor is already placed in the text box, but a straight: `driver.send_keys($claim)` does not work.

I've attached my full code below.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time


PATH = "/Users/brian/Desktop/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.implicitly_wait(300)
driver.get("https://discord.com/login")

username_input = driver.find_element_by_name('email')
username_input.send_keys("email")

password_input = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
password_input.send_keys("password")

driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[type=submit]").click()

time.sleep(5)

driver.get("https://discord.com/channels/944138788383379496/944143465569210378")

ticket = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("ticket-")
ticket.click()

###### This is the inputting text element part below that I'm having so much trouble with.

text_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app-mount"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/main/form/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/span')
text_element.click()
text_element.send_keys("$claim")
text_element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)


print("Success.")
time.sleep(15)
driver.quit()
```

[here is a screenshot of what the html looks like when I inspect the message box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOsjR.png)

Comment: What's the html for the span tag you are trying to send keys to?

Comment: @ArundeepChohan just linked!

Comment: You want to target the div contenteditable='true' tag

Comment: @ArundeepChohan even when I target it, send_keys still isn't sending what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Try `ActionChains`:

```
input_ele = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, r'//div[@role="textbox"]')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", ele)

ActionChains(driver) \
    .move_to_element(input_ele) \
    .send_keys_to_element(input_ele, f'{your message}') \
    .send_keys(keys.Keys.ENTER) \
    .perform()
```